# $\xi =e^{2*\pi/pi }$ , proof that is only two quadratic extention to $\Bbb Q $ that contained in $Q(\xi_p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

$\xi_p =e^{2\pi/p*i }$ , proof that is only two quadratic extention to $\Bbb Q $ that contained in $Q(\xi_p)$
such that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt p)$ if $p=1 mod (4)$ or

$\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-p})$ when $p=3mod(4)$

In the class we proof that $p*(-1/p)=z^2 $ when $z=\sum_{a\in \Bbb F^x_p}(a/p)*\xi_p^a$

when
 (-1/p) = 1 if p=1 mod 4
            and

=-1   if p=3 mod 4

so it`s how I proof the statment. but how to show that this is the only two that possible according to the statment?
I try by contradiction for $z\in \Bbb Q $ such that $\sqrt z \not= \sqrt p $ 
so $\sum_{i=1}^N a_i*\xi_p^i=\sqrt z$
 for some $a_i\in \Bbb Q $ but Its lead me to nowhere...

Comment: Looks a bit strange when you have $\pi$ and $pi$ right next to each other.

Comment: Indeed, $\zeta_p=e^{2\pi i/p}$ looks better than $e^{2*\pi/pi}$.